# Need help in making a search function using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've made a search function using php and mysql. 
I'm using this

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries
            WHERE (`title` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`contents` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

And then I'm echoing it like this

```
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
echo "<p><a href=index.php?id=".$results['id']."> <h3>".$results['title']."</h3></a>".$results['contents']."</p>";
}
```

This shows the title and content. But I want to echo only two lines from the 'content' which contains the query word rather than echoing whole paragraph.
Can anyone help me here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be easily achieved with the help of substr php function. 
Syntax : substr(string,start,length)

Following example will print half of the string from content column.

Referring to your code :

```
    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
   echo "<p><a href=index.php?id=".$results['id']."> <h3>".$results['title']."</h3></a>".substr($results['contents'], strpos($results['contents'], $query), 20)."</p>";
    }
```

Comment: I tried that, But the content shown doesn't include the queried word @Saloni

Comment: Okay if you want the queries word inside then you can make use of the following code:

Comment: John, Can you try the above code with the strpos() function?

Comment: i used strpos who finds the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string

Comment: It works.
But it starts directly from the queried word. How can I get 2-3 words more before it ?

Comment: you may try subtracting the string 4 or 5 words back from the queries string like :
substr($results['contents'], abs(strpos($results['contents'], $query)-15), 20)

Answer (score 0):

> Refer below link[enter link description here](http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-your-own-search-engine-with-php-and-mysql/32733)

Comment: The link doesn't answer my ques. It does'nt contain information about how to show half of the string from column @Vinayagam